# Using variables from script in GDB

Tags: gdb

I would like to write a bat script which call gdb. I want to use script variables in debugging session (like paths, variable names etc.) For example name and location of the config, address ranges to dump or even command.

Is there easy way to do that? I know that there are gdb scripts but I'm not sure how to do that in easy way.
I see that I can access to script variables with "environment" specifier but I can't use it in other way than show and modify this data.

Without considering the sense of this example I would like to have behavior like below.

Bat script:

```
SET MY_COMMAND=run
SET MY_COMMAND2=quit
SET MY_FUNCTION=main
:: GDB CALL ??
```

And expected gdb behavior:

```
break MY_FUNCTION
MY_COMMAND
MY_COMMAND2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will be solution for you:

```
~/.gdbinit
```

You can put gdb commands there, and whenever gdb is started it will execute them.

Well, in fact, in your case it would be easier to use another approach:

```
--command=FILE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is approach I used.